# Are there any properties that occur for every finite subset of a set, but do not apply to the entire set?

Tags: logic

I happened to come across the compactness theorem for propositional logic..
It struck me as odd that we needed to prove that a property such as a model existing for the set exists iff there exists a model for each finite subset.

I feel like such a thing is trivial to claim and could probably have an encompassing proof such as "a set has a property iff every finite subset of the set has the same property"

I'd like if anyone can think of some counter example... where each finite subset has a certain property but the entire set does not.

Comment: Being finite..?

Comment: having a non-empty complement ...

Comment: having a minimum in an open set.

Comment: having a finite powerset .

Comment: The natural numbers are unbounded, whereas every finite subset of $N$ is bounded. So: boundedness is a property which matches your criteria.

Comment: Every finite subset of the reals has measure $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial example of such a property is **finiteness**: if $A$ is any infinite set, then all the finite subsets of $A$ are finite but $A$ itself isn't finite.

A slightly more interesting example is **boundedness** (in the context of metric spaces): every finite subset of a metric space is bounded, but there are metric spaces of unbounded diameter.

---

However, to appreciate the compactness theorem I believe it's most helpful to think about an example coming from logic - but not *first-order* logic! In second-order logic (working in the language of arithmetic) we can write the sentence "Every nonempty set has a least element;" when we add a couple more axioms of basic arithmetic, we get [**second-order Peano arithmetic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation), which is categorical in the sense that it has a unique (up to isomorphism) model, namely $\mathbb{N}$.

But this means compactness **fails** for second-order logic! Consider the language consisting of the usual language of arithmetic together with a new constant symbol $c$, and let $T$ be the theory in this language consisting of second-order Peano arithmetic together with, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the sentence $$c\not=1+1+...+1\quad\mbox{($k$ times)}.$$ Then $T$ **cannot have a model**, even though every finite subset of $T$ does have a model (this is a good exercise).

Answer (score 1):

If get the set $ A=\{1/n\} $ (n is natural) so for a limited subset of $A$ it is compact because is closed and limited in reals, but the entire set is not.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very general.

"think of some counter example... where each finite subset has a certain property but the entire set does not."

This is case-dependent. We could probably list 100 properties of an infinite set that are shared by all it's finite subsets. But we can probably also list 100 other properties of the *same* infinite set that are *not* preserved by it's finite subsets.